# CakePHP- retrieve names of Email Templates

Tags: php, email, cakephp, directory

I'm building a CakePHP application, and I'm trying to allow users to pick an email template from a list and then send it to the addresses that they choose.  I'd like to avoid hard-coding the names of the templates, as they are likely to change and be updated over time.  How can I generate a list (in my controller) of the filenames of all the email templates I have?  I've tried accessing the contents of app/view/Emails/text using the CakePHP Folder class as described here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html

However, that didn't work; I'm unable to get the contents of that directory.  I just need to access the filenames; I can do the rest of the logic once I get them.

Comment: Why are you unable to access the contents? The Folder class has access to everything inside you app folder. At least, that should. Have you tried a vanilla PHP method yet?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for me; I'm not able to access anything via the Folder class.  I even tried simply accessing things in the img folder like this: $dir = new Folder('/img');  $files = $dir->find('.*\.png'); but it comes back empty.  I'm not familiar with vanilla PHP; I'll go look it up

Comment: I just realized that I have url rewriting disabled; could that be causing the inability to read directory contents?

Comment: yes of course. If you could enable rewriting CakePHP can show it's magic better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in any method in your controller:

```
    App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
    $dir = new Folder(APP . 'View/Emails/text/');
    $files = $dir->find('.*\.ctp');
    //print the array to inspect
    pr($files);
```

It should show you all the .ctp template files in /app/View/Emails/text/